# How to use a logical function in a formula as text

Tags: excel

I have a column that contains `5`, `<10`, `>10` and `10`.

I am writing a countif formula and I want to count the cells that contains "<10", but Excel considers the "<" as a logical function. Therefore, the result is not correct.

The complete formula is:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Master_tbl[Systemstatus],"*TABG*",Master_tbl[Klassen],"<10AT",Master_tbl[Erfassungsdatum],">=01.01.2017",Master_tbl[Erfassungsdatum],"<=31.01.2017",Master_tbl[Auftragsart],{"YAEL","YAFD","YALP","YAPL"},Master_tbl[IH-Leistungsart],{"T01"."T02"."T03"."T04"."T35"}))
```

and my challenge is `Master_tbl[Klassen],"<10AT"`

Is there any solution to bring the "<" in my formula as a normal character?

Thanks,
Dio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an equal sign at the front:

```
Master_tbl[Klassen],"=<10AT"
```

I'm not 100% sure on this, but I believe it works from the few tests I've done.

Comment: your are right, but I didn't mention that the columnt can have "10" value as well. Therefore, it will be counted two times. I updated my question. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Consider that in the column there are following values: "5", "10", "<10" and ">10". Your solution, `Master_tbl[Klassen],"=<10AT"` will count "<10" and "10". This is because of "=". I hope I could explain what I mean.

Comment: @Dio Yes, but as shown in the linked picture in my previous comment, that is not happening.

Comment: You are right. Sorry. I made a mistake in my test. Thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: @Dio No problem n_n